# MikTex Package Update Issue on Windows 8

Tags: packages, miktex, windows, texmaker, updating

I have been using MikTex on Windows XP and 7 for few months now and I faced no issues in installing packages that needs to be done on the fly.

However, with Windows 8, the packages are not updated at all.

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

As an example, I tried to build the following "http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs573/fa2011/Homework/hw5.tex" which requires the "fullpage" package. However, I always get build error saying,

> ! LaTeX Error: File `fullpage.sty' not found.Type X to quit or
>    to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter
>   file name:! Emergency stop. \usepackage

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Open the MikTeX options (adm) and set it to install from the internet. Choose a repository.

Comment: @Sigur: I actually did that, but not result. I even tried swapping among different repository.

Comment: After choose a repository use the package manager to find and install new packages and then run the *refresh database*.

Comment: I actually get an Write error message. I am also logged in as Admin, so I figure authentication should not be an issue.

Comment: It seems to me, it is once again a permission problem, cf. [the memory dump file could not be found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81739/the-memory-dump-file-could-not-be-found).

Comment: @Speravir: Looks like the security in Windows 8 is very tight. Perhaps this is something the MikTex developers have to look into for future release for an universal solution, right?

Comment: So yo can/must confirm what is written in the other answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to have the packages updated while running TexMaker. This process always failed if I did not start TexMaker as an Administrator.

The issue is resolved if Texmaker is run as Administrator. I guess this is something both Texmaker and MikTex should look into resolving.

Comment: I guess, yo have MiKTeX installed under `C:\Program Files` or an equivalent? You could try to reinstall _outside_ of it. [Relocate MiKTeX 2.9?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/relocate-miktex-2-9/56322#56322) should help you.

Answer (score 1):

@Shamim Hafiz might be right, because what solve my problem was to install the MiKTeX 2.9 in the compatibility mode pointing out that MiKTeX used to work well in Win7. I completed the installation and then, I also executed the Texwork editor (the default editor installed with MiKTeX) in the compatibility mode.

After checking that my file was compiling ok in that editor, I saved the configuration in the Windows assistant by saying that my problem was solved by executing as if it were Win7. Finally, I executed my editor (Texmaker) and everything went well.

My opinion is that Win8 is the problem although I had been working with Win8+MiKTeX 2.7+Texmaker for quite a long time, but suddenly it crashed. But now it's working again.